# What is the problem with a generalized kinetic term as $K^{\mu\nu}(x)\partial_\mu\phi\partial_\nu\phi$?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, lorentz-symmetry, poincare-symmetry, invariants

For field theory in flat spacetime, the most general kinetic term that I can think of for a field is $$K^{\mu\nu}(x)\partial_\mu\phi\partial_\nu\phi$$ where $K^{\mu\nu}(x)$ is an arbitrary second rank tensor (field). Since all greek indices are contracted, this is a Lorentz invariant possibility. Why are such terms never considered in field theories at flat spacetime?

Comment: If it depends on $x$, it's not Lorentz or translation invariant.

Comment: In common notation I think you mean $K^{\mu \nu}$

Comment: @user2723984 Sorry about that. Corrected now

Comment: @Javier Please see my comment on tparker's answer.

Comment: The problem is not the indices, it's the fact that $K$ is an explicit function of the coordinates, and so its expression will change after a Lorentz transformation.

Answer (score 1):

It's not Poincare invariant (because it's not translationally invariant), so it doesn't satisfy the postulated symmetries of special relativity.

Comment: Doesn't $K^{\mu\nu}$ change under LT as $K^{\mu\nu}=\Lambda^\mu_{~\rho}\Lambda^\nu_{~\sigma}K^{\rho\sigma}$?

Comment: But you have two more $\Lambda$s coming from two $\partial^\mu\phi$s. So Lorentz indices are contracted. Why is this not Lorentz invariant then?

Comment: @mithusenguota Oh oops, you're right. The problem is actually that the $x$ inside the argument of the $K$ also picks up a factor of $\Lambda^{-1}$ which isn't cancelled by anything.

Answer (score 0):

Consider just $T=\partial^2\phi(x)$ under $x^\mu\to x'^\mu=\Lambda^\mu{}_\nu\, x^\nu+a^\mu$
.

Then 
$$
\begin{align*}
T\to T'&=\partial'^2\,\phi'(x')\\
&=\partial^2\,\phi'(x')
\end{align*}
$$

Notice that there is a choice in how $\phi$ transforms independent of how the coordinates transform.
To keep $T$ invariant, we must choose
$\phi(x)\to \phi'(x')=\phi(x)$

Similarly for $T=K^{\mu\nu}(x)\,\partial_\mu \phi(x)\,\partial_\nu\phi(x)$,

$$
\begin{align*}
T\to T'
&=K'^{\mu\nu}(x')\,\partial'_\mu \phi'(x')\,\partial'_\nu\phi'(x')\\
&=\lambda_{\mu}{}^{\rho}\Lambda_{\nu}{}^\sigma K'^{\mu\nu}(x')\,\partial_\rho \phi(x)\,\partial_\sigma\phi(x)
\end{align*}
$$

where the transformation for $\phi$ is as before. If in addition we choose, $K^{\mu\nu}(x)\to K'^{\mu\nu}(x')$ such that
 $$ \lambda_{\mu}{}^{\rho}\Lambda_{\nu}{}^\sigma K'^{\mu\nu}(x')=K^{\rho\sigma}(x)\tag{1}$$

then $T$ would be invariant. Note that this choice is allowed and doesn't violate Poincare invariance as that is how we have defined the field to transform. Note that this is exactly $\Lambda^{T}K'\Lambda=K$

However, $K^{\mu\nu}$ being a tensor field must also satisfy

$$K'^{\mu\nu}(x')=\Lambda^\mu{}_\lambda\Lambda^\nu{}_\delta K^{\lambda\delta}(x')\tag{2}$$

Substituting (2) in (1) and simplifying one gets $$K^{\rho\sigma}(x')=K^{\rho\sigma}(x)\,\, \forall \, x,x' $$

which makes $$K^{\mu\nu}\propto g^{\mu\nu} $$